# How to create a new dataframe that contains the value changes from multiple columns between two exisitng dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking at football player development over a five year period.

I have two dataframes (DFs), one that contains all 20 year-old strikers from FIFA 17 and another that contains all 25 year-old strikers from FIFA 22. I want to create a third DF that contains the attribute changes for each player. There are about 30 columns denoting each attribute, e.g. tackling, shooting, passing etc. So I want the new DF to contain +3 for tackling, +2 for shooting, +6 for passing etc.

The best way of solving this that I can think of is by merging the two DFs and then applying a function to every column that gives the difference between the x and y values, which represent the FIFA 17 and FIFA 22 data respectively.

Any tips much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated, use the difference of the dataframes. I'm suspecting they are not **ALL** NaN values, as you'll only get that for rows where the same player isn't in both 17 and 22 Fifas.

When I do it, there are only 533 player in both 17 and 22 (that were 20 years old in Fifa 17 and 25 in Fifa 22).

Here's an example:

import pandas as pd

```
fifa17 = pd.read_csv('D:/test/fifa/players_17.csv')
fifa17 = fifa17[fifa17['age'] == 20]
fifa17 = fifa17.set_index('sofifa_id')

fifa22 = pd.read_csv('D:/test/fifa/players_22.csv')
fifa22 = fifa22[fifa22['age'] == 25]
fifa22 = fifa22.set_index('sofifa_id')

compareCols = ['pace', 'shooting', 'passing', 'dribbling', 'defending', 
               'physic', 'attacking_crossing', 'attacking_finishing', 
               'attacking_heading_accuracy', 'attacking_short_passing', 
               'attacking_volleys', 'skill_dribbling', 'skill_curve', 
               'skill_fk_accuracy', 'skill_long_passing', 
               'skill_ball_control', 'movement_acceleration', 
               'movement_sprint_speed', 'movement_agility', 
               'movement_reactions', 'movement_balance', 'power_shot_power', 
               'power_jumping', 'power_stamina', 'power_strength', 
               'power_long_shots', 'mentality_aggression', 
               'mentality_interceptions', 'mentality_positioning', 
               'mentality_vision', 'mentality_penalties', 
               'mentality_composure', 'defending_marking_awareness', 
               'defending_standing_tackle', 'defending_sliding_tackle']

df = fifa22[compareCols] - fifa17[compareCols]


df = df.dropna(axis=0)
df = pd.merge(df,fifa22[['short_name']], how = 'left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
           pace  shooting  ...  defending_sliding_tackle     short_name
sofifa_id                  ...                                         
205291     -1.0       0.0  ...                       3.0     H. Stengel
205988     -7.0       3.0  ...                      -1.0        L. Shaw
206086      0.0       8.0  ...                       5.0     H. Toffolo
206113     -2.0      21.0  ...                      -2.0      S. Gnabry
206463     -3.0       8.0  ...                       3.0     J. Dudziak
        ...       ...  ...                       ...            ...
236311     -2.0      -1.0  ...                      18.0         M. Rog
236393      2.0       5.0  ...                       0.0   Marc Cardona
236415      3.0       1.0  ...                       9.0      R. Alfani
236441     10.0      31.0  ...                      18.0      F. Bustos
236458      1.0       0.0  ...                       5.0  A. Poungouras

[533 rows x 36 columns]
```

Comment: awesome! this is exactly what I wanted, thank you very much. let me know if you'd like me to update you the progress of my project. all the best

Comment: Ya would love an update. I love working with sports data (including video games as well.)

Answer (score 0):

You might subtract `pandas.DataFrame`s consider following simple example

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,2],'Y':[3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X':[10,20],'Y':[30,40]})
dfdiff = df2 - df1
print(dfdiff)
```

gives output

```
    X   Y
0   9  27
1  18  36
```

Comment: Thank you I did try this but all I get is NaN values. I thought it might be an indexing issue so changed the indexes of both DFs to player_ID but still it returns all NaN values. I appreciate your swift response.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution but it is very tedious as it requires a line of code for each and every attribute.

I'm simply assigning a new column for each attribute change. So for Passing, for instance, the code is:

```
mergedDF = mergedDF.assign(PassingChange = mergedDF.Passing_x - mergedDF.Passing_y)
```