# How to create a new dataframe that contains the value changes from multiple columns between two exisitng DFs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The first two tables represent snippets from the first and second dataframes, respectively. I am trying to create a new dataframe that contains the numerical changes for each attribute

[image]

Please also see my other post for how I framed the same question in a different way: [How to create a new dataframe that contains the value changes from multiple columns between two exisitng dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72803474/how-to-create-a-new-dataframe-that-contains-the-value-changes-from-multiple-colu/72803556#72803556)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `ID` and `Name` columns as index then do substraction

```py
out = (df2.set_index(['ID', 'Name']) - df1.set_index(['ID', 'Name'])).reset_index()
```

```
print(df1)

   ID Name   A   B
0   1    a  89  91

print(df2)

   ID Name   A   B
0   1    a  95  98

print(out)

   ID Name  A  B
0   1    a  6  7
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is super helpful. I didn't know you can have multiple indexes